# Find derivative of $y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

The solution is given as $\frac{2}{1+x^2}$. But is it a complete solution ?

**My Attempt**

$$
2\tan^{-1}x=\begin{cases}\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2},\quad |x|\leq 1\\
\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2},\quad |x|>1 \;\&\; x>0\\
-\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2},\quad |x|>1 \;\&\;x>0\\
\end{cases}\\
\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\begin{cases}2\tan^{-1}x,\quad |x|\leq 1\\
\pi-2\tan^{-1}x,\quad |x|>1 \;\&\; x>0\\
-\pi-2\tan^{-1}x,\quad |x|>1 \;\&\;x>0\\
\end{cases}\\
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg[\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\bigg]=\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dx}[2\tan^{-1}x]=\frac{2}{1+x^2},\quad |x|\leq 1\\
\frac{d}{dx}[\pm\pi-2\tan^{-1}x]=\frac{-2}{1+x^2},|x|>1 
\end{cases}
$$
Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

- $(\sin^{-1}x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

then apply chain rule $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)=\frac{\frac{2(1+x^2)-4x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}}{\sqrt{1-{\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)}^2}}=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)|1-x^2|}$

Comment: could u comment on my attempt ?. why am i getting two case ?

Comment: @ss1729 so you are looking for a direct proof?

Comment: @ss1729 the final result seems to be correct, but why use the $tan^{-1}$ for the derivation?

Comment: Why do toy thunk that you should be getting one case?

Comment: @gimusi u mean there are two cases right ?.not just $\frac{2}{1+x^2}$

Comment: @ss1729 Yes since when factor out the terms under the square root we have an absolute value.

Comment: So you mean $y'=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$ is incomplete right ?. bcz thats wht was mentioned as answer in my reference. thats where my doubt is

Comment: @ss1729 yes by chain rule I've derived exactly your result

Comment: @ss1729 we also have that $-1\le \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \le 1$ thus there are not further conditions on x

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***
Your answer seems correct to me even I don't really understand the need of tan function

$$y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}  \implies \sin y=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$
Differentiate 
$$y'\cos(y)=\frac {-2(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
use the fact that $$\sin^2(y)+\cos^2(y)=1$$

Comment: hw do u proceed it without substituting for x ?

Comment: differentiate both sides and note that $(\sin(y))'=\cos(y)y'$

Comment: what about RHS ?. $\cos yy'=\frac{(1+x^2).2-2x.2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{2+4x^2+2x^4-4x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{2(1+x^4)}{(1+x^2)^2}$ Now what ?

Comment: you have the value of $\sin(y)$ use $cos^2(y)+sin^2(y)=1$ to get rid of the $cos(y)$

Comment: This answer is good when you dont know the derivative of arcsin function ....